# store selected radio button values from different groups upon clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, radio-button, radio-group

I am rendering different groups of radio buttons for product variant options. (For example: a t-shirt can have 3 different radio button groups : size, material, color). Now I am trying to store the user selected radio button values in an array and add the product variant to the cart. I am storing the values with an onclick event on the radio buttons. But because of this, if I change my size choice from XS to S, then both of the XS and S values get added to my array. But I only need the final radio button values to be stored in my array so that I can compare it with my json data and find the variant id. Therefore, I am trying to store all the selected radio button values as an onclick event on the add to cart button, that way it will only store the final selected radio button values. However, I am not sure how to access all the radio button values from different groups in this part. Any help will be appreciated. This is my code so far:

```
         <div class="radios">
                    {% for product_option in product.options_with_values %} 
                        <p>{{ product_option.name }} -- </p>
                    
                        {% for value in product_option.values %}
                            <input type="radio" id = "{{ value }}" name="{{ product_option.name}}" value="{{ value }}" >
                            <label for="{{ value }}">{{ value }}</label>  
                        {% endfor %}
                      <br>
                  {% endfor %}

                  <script>
                         var optionsArray = [];
                         var filteredOptionsArray = [];
                          document.querySelector('.radios').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                          optionsArray.push(e.target.value);
                          filteredOptionsArray = optionsArray.filter(function (el) {
                            return el != null;
                           });
                           console.log(filteredOptionsArray);
                        //   console.log(optionsArray.toString());
                      })
                  </script>
                </div>
        <div class="quantity-add">
            <div class="input-quantity">
                <input class="input-quantity" type="number" min="1" placeholder="1" name="quantity" value="1"> 
                <input type="hidden" id="add-cart" name="id" data-productid="{{ product.variants[0].id }}" value="{{ product.variants[0].id }}" data-variant-title="{{ product.variants[0].title }}" />
            </div>
            <div class="cart-button">
                <button class="cart-btn" type="submit" value="Add To Cart">ADD</button> 

                <!-- script for adding the selected variant to the cart -->
                <script>
                    document.querySelector('.cart-btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
                        for (let i=0; i < variantsArray.length; i++) {
                            if ((JSON.stringify(filteredOptionsArray))== (JSON.stringify(variantsArray[i].options))) {
                                console.log('stringify match check works');
                                console.log(variantsArray[i].options);
                                document.querySelector('#add-cart').value = variantsArray[i].id;
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log('stringify match check failed');
                                console.log(variantsArray[i].options);
                            }
                        }
                    })
                </script>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

found it, I needed to do this:

```
const checkedRadios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked');
const radio_values = Array.from(checkedRadios, radio => radio.value);
```